# Can i link a js file with a jsx file ? react only for front (not react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I want to show my `home.jsx` file content into `app.js` file.

I use React for the frontend (not react-native) and Symfony 5 for the backend. Later, my final goal is a simple button.

Is it possible? I don't know what is my mistake.
I created an `app.jsx` in bonus.

Here are my files:

- [home.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWnV7.png)
- [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59idj.png)
- [app.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB7QJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Home.jsx` file, instead of:

```js
  export { Home as default };
```

you have to default export the `Home` component like this:

```js
  export default Home;
```

Then, in your `App.jsx` file, import the `Home` component like this:

```js
  import Home from './Home';
```

Here is a good article that explains the difference between Default & Named exports

https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Comment:  let me know if it helps

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow